# codeigniter controller function parameter

Tags: function, codeigniter, view, parameters, controller

```
class Mymodel extends CI_Model {
    public function getJp($jp=""){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM daftarpaket WHERE jenisproduk = ?";
        $data = $this->db->query($sql, $jp);
        return $data->result_array();
    }
}

class Controller extends CI_Controller {
    public function daftarPaket($jp=""){
        $data = $this->mymodel->getJp("$jp");
        return $data->result_array();
    }
}
```

how can i foreach my result_array of daftarpaket and daftarpaket parameter i take from value of select option before i click submit button?

TY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your controller file

```
class Controller extends CI_Controller {
public function daftarPaket($jp=""){
    $data['jp'] = $this->mymodel->getJp("$jp");

}
```

In view for select option

```
   <select><?php if(count($jp)>0){ foreach($jp as $jpdata){  ?> <option value="<?php echo $jpdata['name'] ?>" ><?php echo $jpdata['name'] ?></option><?php }}?></select>
```

Comment: `<select id ='Jproduk'>
 <option value=""></option>
 <option value="game">game</option>
</select>`



i want to foreach (daftarpaket(selected value)), thats what i mean